# Fixed sidebar menu on mobile CSS

Tags: css

I have a sidebar menu with a position fixed, but when  I scroll it has about 100vh scroll, and some buttons with bottom:0 , and that elements are shown after scroll.

How can I remove that scroll, to see all fixed/absolute elements on display?

```
.v-sidebar-menu .on-desktop .vsm_collapsed{
    position: fixed!important;
    height: 100vh!important;
}

.on-mobile-buttons{
    display: flex!important;
    position: fixed!important;
    max-width: 100vw!important;
    width: 100vw!important;
    justify-content: space-between;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    right: 0;
    flex-direction: row;
    a button, div button{
        max-width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        max-width: 100px;

    }
}
.main-container{
    display: flex;
}
body {
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif !important;
    background-color: rgba(106, 135, 148, 0.8);
    min-height:100%;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
html{
    background-color: rgba(106, 135, 148, 0.8);
    min-height:100%;
    background-size:cover;
}

  <div id="app">
    <div class="main-container">
      <sidebar-menu  :menu="menu" :collapsed="collapsed" class="on-desktop" @item-click="onItemClick">//here is the sidebar
        <i slot="toggle-icon" class="fas fa-arrows-alt-h"></i>
      </sidebar-menu>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: post both html and css code to reproduce the problem

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle example or html code?

Comment: please add html code also and create a code snippet

Comment: I can't post whole code, because is to much, is in a VueJs app. I update my post, with code that I think is relevant.

Comment: Can you at least post the rendered html; or post the `sidebar-menu` component (and tag this question with Vue)

Comment: I found the solution. Strange thing, but is from my font-family,from body. If I place it in html it's ok.